# Possible bug: item utc date values aren't actually in UTC

Tags: api, utc, podio

this evening I discovered something strange. 30 minutes ago I created an item with a timestamp burned into a date app field. I'm in UTC+2. 30 minutes ago that meant

- 18:59 in UTC
- 20:59 in UTC + 2

However the API returned

```
{"start"=>"2016-10-16 22:59:05",
"start_date_utc"=>"2016-10-16",
"start_time_utc"=>"20:59:05",
"start_time"=>"22:59:05",
"start_utc"=>"2016-10-16 20:59:05",
"start_date"=>"2016-10-16"}
```

Podio seems thus to return my local time as utc, and add the timezone offset (UTC+2) once more on top of that for the localized.

Please give me a status and fix, or let me know what I'm missing :)

Comment: Can you also share how you are setting value?

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on your Podio user settings, so if you want to set value `2016-10-21 14:15:00 +0200` and your account settings are UTC+02, then simply send `2016-10-21 14:15:00` value to API and it will be properly converted and stored. And if authenticated as app, then assumed timezone is UTC.

More experiments and examples are here: [Podio: which TimeZone is used while setting DateTime field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187495/podio-which-timezone-is-used-while-setting-datetime-field-value)