# Flaw in Podio Date fields using the API

Tags: php, datetime, podio

So i've found a flaw in the Podio Date fields when updating them via the API and its rather frustrating.

When getting and setting Date fields via the API it pulls/requires it to be set, in UTC time. It then converts to the user's Timezone based on their profile.

HOWEVER, if you set the Date field to midnight (00:00:00), it ignores time completely and will always just leave it as the day, not auto converting it to the correct time. (For example, 6/29/17 00:00:00, should convert to 6/28/17 18:00:00 for me in MST, but it just stays as 6/29/17 in Podio)

This is highly frustrating when trying to develop automations. For example I am taking the a date field, adding days/hours to it, and if it happens to land on 12:00 am, even though I want it to convert back to local timezones in Podio, it just stays on the day. I thought maybe adding some seconds to it might cause this behavior to change, however, both 00:00:01, and 00:00:59, both have the same result.

The only work around was to add 1 minute more. This is not a good solution, however the only one I was able to find.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: FYI, haven't noticed this with c# podio.net wrapper.  something like: 
var some = newItem.Field<DateItemField>("date");
some.Start = date.ToUniversalTime();
works for me.  I.E. can you confirm that this happens because of podio or is it an artifact of the PHP wrapper?

Comment: Can you please share code sample that will reproduce this issue?

Comment: I was experimenting with how Podio handles timezones and here are results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187495/podio-which-timezone-is-used-while-setting-datetime-field-value/40187496

Answer (score 0):

Setting time 00:00:00 - 00:00:00 from and to, then it consider only date, api may ignore the time for valid reason.

For automation set the user time zone to particular timezone and set the UTC time accordingly. 00:00:01, and 00:00:59 -Instead of changing the secs parameter, make change in Mins parameter for eg : 00:00:00 - 00:50:00. It is working for me.

Setting 00:00:00 value to api, ignoring the parameter may be raised as a bug.